# Nextjs i18n middleware redirect issue

Tags: typescript, next.js, internationalization, http-redirect

I'm setting up localization in my NextJS project, and its working well except for one edge case. The locale is encoded in the url, except when its the default locale.

Here is my middleware function:

```
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  const splitPath = pathname.split('/');
  const currentLng = splitPath[1];

  // If lng is default, convert to root path /
  if (currentLng === fallbackLng) {
    const newPath = `/${splitPath.slice(2).join('/')}`;
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(newPath, req.url));
  }

  const pathnameIsMissingValidLocale =
    !languages.some((loc) => {
      return pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}/`) || pathname === `/${loc}`;
    }) && !pathname.startsWith('/_next');

  // Redirect if lng in path is not supported
  if (pathnameIsMissingValidLocale) {
    const lng = getBestLocale(req.headers.get('Accept-Language'));

    if (lng !== fallbackLng) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lng}${pathname}`, req.url));
    } else {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(
        new URL(`/${fallbackLng}${pathname}`, req.url)
      );
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

The `getBestLocale` function tries to get the ideal locale from the request headers. The problem occurs when someone's headers don't match the default locale. If they attempt to change to the default locale, they will get redirected back to the locale matching their header. For example:

Default locale: "en"

User locale headers: "es"

When the user visits `website.com` they are redirected to `website.com/es` correctly. If they try to change to default language with the language picker it redirects them to `website.com/en` which will get redirected to `website.com/` to hide the default locale, but this will then redirect them again to `website.com/es`.

Everything works perfectly if I don't hide the default locale in the URL, but it would be preferred to do so.

Is there a clean way to fix this?